# Proof Verification: Converse to Strong Law of Large Numbers.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, random-variables

I want to verify my proof to the following question.

Let $\{X_i\}$ be i.i.d random variables with $E(|X_i|) = \infty$.

Show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left|X_n\right| > nk) = \infty$ and $\limsup \frac{\left|X_n\right|}{n} = \infty$ almost surely, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

My proof

Note since $X_i$ are i.i.d random variable, we may consider $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left|X\right| > nk)$

$\int \left|X\right| dP = \infty$. Let $A_n =  \{ \omega \colon n<\left|X\right| \leq n+1 \}$, where $X = X_1$. We will first consider the case $k = 1$.

Then note $E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{A_n} \left|X\right| dP + \int_{\{\omega \colon 0 \leq \left|X(\omega)\right| < 1 \}} \left|X\right| dP = \infty$, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{A_n} \left|X\right| dP = \infty$.

Now, since all elements in the infinite sum is positive, we may rearrange the sum to get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left|X\right| >n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(A_n) = \infty$.

And $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{A_n} \left|X\right| dP \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)(n+1) = \sum_{n} n P(A_n) + \sum_{n} P(A_n) = \infty$.

Since $\sum nP(A_n) > \sum P(A_n)$, we have $\sum_{n} n P(A_n) = \infty$.

Now to extend it to general case of $k > 1$, we note that

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left|X\right| > nk) \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left|X\right| > nk+1) \geq \ldots \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left|X\right| > nk+(k-1))$.

Hence, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left|X\right| > nk) < \infty$, $\sum_{n} P(\left|X\right| > n) < \infty$ too, a contradiction.

Now to prove the second claim, fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\sum_n P(\left|X_n\right| > nk) = \infty$ and $X_n$ are independent, by Borel-Cantelli Lemma, $P(\frac{\left|X_n\right|}{n}>k i.o.) = 1$. This shows that $\limsup \frac{\left|X_n\right|}{n} = \infty$ almost surely.

Thank you.

Comment: When you generalized to $k> 1$, I'm not sure how you concluded that $\sum_{n} P(\left|X\right| > n) < \infty$ from the inequality chain above that line.

It looks like you'd need for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left|X\right| > nk+(k-1)) = \infty$ to be true in order to derive that conclusion

Comment: @JamieAlizadeh My idea was, say we take $k = 3$, then each of the sum $P(\left|X\right|> 3)+P(\left|X\right| > 6) + \ldots$, $P(\left|X\right| > 4) + P(\left|X\right| > 7) + \ldots$, $P(\left|X\right| > 5) + P(\left|X\right| > 8)+\ldots$ are finite, and so $P(\left|X\right|> 3)+P(\left|X\right| > 6) + \ldots + P(\left|X\right| > 4) + P(\left|X\right| > 7) + \ldots + P(\left|X\right| > 5) + P(\left|X\right| > 8)+\ldots = \sum_{n=3}^\infty P(\left|X\right|>n) < \infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing how you'd go about proving that. Because for $k = 3$ you don't have have $3|4$, $3|7$ etc. So you'd need a finite set of divisors to partition all the natural numbers in order to account for $4$, $7$, etc.

Comment: @JamieAlizadeh well I'm partitioning \{3,6,9 \ldots\}, \{4,7,10, \ldots \}$ and $\{5,8,11, \ldots \}$, and my infinite sum is $A_1 = \sum_n P(\left|X\right|> 3n)$, $A_2 = \sum_n P(\left|X\right| > 3n+1)$, $A_3 = \sum_n P(\left|X\right| > 3n+2)$. $A_1+A_2+A_3 = \sum_{n=3}^\infty P(\left|X\right| > n)$, and so if each of $A_1, A_2,A_3$ are finite, it's a contradiction.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah that should work :^)